# Evaluating a limit involving the power of specially structured matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $k\times k$ right-stochastic matrix $A$ be defined as follows:

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
p & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1-p\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right],$$
where $p$ satisfies $0<p<1$.

I am interested in what happens to $A$'s $n$-th power, $A^n$ as $n$ gets large.  Specifically, I am wondering if there is a closed form expression (in terms of $k$ and $p$) for a the top-left cell of: 
$$B=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A^n,$$
that is, what is $x=e_1Be_1^T$ where $e_1=[1,\ldots,0]$ is a row vector containing a one followed by $k-1$ zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is primitive because each of the $k$ states is path connected to the others. Hence the eigenvalue $1$ is dominant and simple (Perron-Frobenius theorem). It follows that if $v$ is the left eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, and it is scaled to become a probability vector (so that the sum of its entries is $1$), then every row of $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$ is the equilibrium distribution $v^T$ and your $x$ is the first entry of $v$.

Therefore, the problem boils down to finding the left eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $1$, but given the structure of $A$, it is obvious that $v^T$ takes the form of $(x, \frac{1-x}{k-1}, \ldots, \frac{1-x}{k-1})$. So, the problem further reduces to a linear equation in a single variable $x$. You may continue from here.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Indeed this is very simple.  $x=\frac{1}{p+k(1-p)}$. Thanks for the hint!